# Reset the automatic invoice generation to 000/'current year' at the start of a new fiscal year in Excel VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I have a working code which automatically increments invoice number in the format 112/2020, 113/2020, and so on (for the fiscal year 2020) when the user inputs other details in a userform and hits submit.

What I want is to reset this invoice number to 001/2021 as soon as the fiscal year changes in the month of April according to my fiscal year function. And it should do that every year when the fiscal year increments.

The function I am using to calculate current fiscal year is given below

```
If Month(dDate) <= 3 Then
    FinancialYear = Year(dDate) - 1
  Else
    FinancialYear = Year(dDate)
  End If
End Function
```

I am incrementing the invoice numbers automatically when user hits submit on a form using:

```
.Cells(emptyRow, 2) = Format(Int(Left(.Cells(emptyRow - 1, 2).Value, 3)) + 1, "000") & "/" & current_year
```

where

```
emptyRow = WorksheetFunction.CountA(nwb.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A:A")) + 1 'To calculate next empty row

current_year = FinancialYear(Date)
```

The full code is(I haven't included other unnecessary stuff):

```
Function FinancialYear(dDate As Date) As Integer
  If Month(dDate) <= 3 Then
    FinancialYear = Year(dDate) - 1
  Else
    FinancialYear = Year(dDate)
  End If
End Function

Sub Submit()
    Dim nwb As Workbook
    Set nwb = Workbooks.Open("C:\Users\CHAMARA2\Downloads\TestDB.xlsx")

    Dim emptyRow As Long

    Dim current_year As String
    emptyRow = WorksheetFunction.CountA(nwb.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A:A")) + 1

    With nwb.Sheets("Sheet1")

        .Cells(emptyRow, 1) = emptyRow - 1  'serial number

        'If current_year = 2020 Or current_year = 2022 Or current_year = 2023 Or current_year = 2024 Or current_year = 2025 Then .Cells(emptyRow, 2) = "000/" & current_year

        .Cells(emptyRow, 2) = Format(Int(Left(.Cells(emptyRow - 1, 2).Value, 3)) + 1, "000") & "/" & current_year

    End With
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Right before generating your incremented invoice number just check if invoice number 1 of the current year  `001/2021` already exists in your invoices. Eg by using the [WorksheetFunction.Match method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.worksheetfunction.match).

If that invoice number exists, then the invoice counter is already in the current year, if it does not exist we need to reset the counter to 0 because no invoice was written in the current year yet.

```
Dim FirstInvoice As String
FirstInvoice = "001" & "/" & current_year

Dim MatchInvoice As Double
On Error Resume Next 'next line will error if invoice 001/2021 does not exist yet
MatchInvoice = Applicarion.WorksheetFunction.Match(FirstInvoice, RangeOfInvoceNumbers, 0)
On Error Goto 0  're-enable error reporting

If MatchInvoice = 0 Then
    'first invoice of the current year does not exist so
    'reset your invoice counter to 0 here
End If

'proceed generating your increment as you did before.
```

This will not reset the counter directly in 1. January but whenever the first invoice is generated in the new year. So this even works if you write your first invoice in June for example.

---

A bit off topic:

Note that using this format `001/2021` will sort like this:

```
001/2020
001/2021
001/2022
002/2020
002/2022
002/2023
```

So you might consider a better format like:

```
2020/001
2020/002
2021/001
2021/002
2022/001
2022/002
```

that will automatically sort year wise.

If you keep the actual stored invoice number numeric like `2020001` and just use the number format `0000"/"000` to show it like `2020/001` for better human readability, you can even use the `MAX` function to find the latest invoice number in your invoices and increment that by calculating `+1`.

Then you could also use `Application.WorksheetFunction.Max` to check if you need to reset and increment more easily

```
Dim FirstInvoiceCurrentYear As Long
FirstInvoiceCurrentYear = cLng(current_year & "001")

Dim CurrentInvoice As Long
CurrentInvoice = Application.WorksheetFunction.Max(RangeOfInvoceNumbers)

Dim NextInvoiceNumber As Long
If FirstInvoiceCurrentYear > CurrentInvoice Then
     NextInvoiceNumber = FirstInvoiceCurrentYear 
Else
     NextInvoiceNumber = CurrentInvoice + 1
End If
```

So you see choosing a better format makes your life much easier in some points.

You just need to ensure that any cell containing the invoice number is set to number format `0000"/"000` if you then enter `2020001` into that cell it will automaticall show up as `2020/001`, but the cell is still a number you can calculate with.

Comment: I am sorry for these easy questions but what will be the RangeOfInvoiceNumber? Will it be the invoice number column?

And should I include your code inside With or outside it?

Comment: @RaghavChamadiya Yes, just set/replace `RangeOfInvoiceNumbers` to something like `ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Invoices").Range("A:A")` if your invoice numbers are in column A of the sheet `Invoices`. • This code needs no `With` statement if you specify the worksheet and range for `RangeOfInvoiceNumber` like above.

Comment: Thank you so much for taking all this effort, and I can't change the format of the invoice number as it's fixed.

Comment: @RaghavChamadiya darn, would have been much easier to work with. Still the first solution should work with your format.

Answer (score 0):

you could check previous row invoice number last 4 digits (for instance with `IIF()` function):

```
Dim nwb As Workbook
Set nwb = Workbooks.Open("C:\Users\CHAMARA2\Downloads\TestDB.xlsx")

Dim current_year As String
current_year = FinancialYear(Date)

With nwb.Sheets("Sheet1")
    With .Cells(.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Offset(1)
        .Value = .Row - 1 'serial number
        .Offset(, 1) = Format(Int(Left$(IIf(Right$(.Offset(-1, 1).Value, 4) = current_year, .Offset(-1, 1).Value, 0), 3)) + 1, "000") & "/" & current_year
    End With
End With
```